# Add Master Page form values not returning on request.form

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

UPDATED ISSUE:

I converted some pages to use master pages and they worked fine.

When doing request.form on child page (form declaration is in master page) I get a null value (just doing Request.Form("field") returns NULL but before master pages it worked

NOTE:  ALL the code worked fine before implementing master pages!!

The button code is:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnPACheck" runat="server"  Text="<%$Resources:share,btnPACheck %>" onclick="btnPACheck_Click" />
```

The view soruce on the html page for the button is:

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnPACheck" value="Continue" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnPACheck" />
```

The onclick code is long but it is declared like this (and first line has the debug line placed on it and it is not getting to it):

```
protected void btnPACheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool validPA = false;
```

Master page is below:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterPageSiteWide.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPageSiteWide" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
<%@ Register src="~/ucBanner.ascx" TagName="Banner" TagPrefix="ucBanner"  %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            background: url(page-bg.gif) repeat-x top left #5997C8;  
            CLIP: rect(19px 65px 50px 10px);
            margin-top: 10px;
            margin-bottom:30px;
            margin-right: 40px;
            margin-left: 60px;
            width:80%;
        }


        TD.bluerow {
            height: .10pc;
            background-color: #000066;
        }

        TD.medbluerow {
            height: .0005pc;
            background-color: #6699CC;
        }   

        .panel_with_padding {
             padding-top:10px;
             padding-left:10px;
             padding-right:10px;
             padding-bottom:10px; 
         }

    </style>

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>

<body>

    <form id="form1" runat="server" method="post">

        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" EnableScriptGlobalization="true" EnableScriptLocalization="true" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>


        <asp:RoundedCornersExtender Corners="All" TargetControlID="MainPanel" BorderColor="Black" ID="RoundedCornersExtender1" runat="server"></asp:RoundedCornersExtender>

        <asp:Panel BackColor="White" runat="server" ID="MainPanel" CssClass="panel_with_padding">

            <div>            
                <br />
                <div>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblTopHeading" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="X-Large" Text=""></asp:Label>
                </div>


                <br />
                <ucBanner:Banner ID="bannerStrip" runat="server"></ucBanner:Banner>
                <br />

                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">        
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

            </div>

            <br /><br />
            <hr />    
            <div>
                © Copyright 20xx-2012, Ford Motor Company. All rights reserved.
            </div>

        </asp:Panel>



    </form>





</body>
</html>
```

Content page (part of cant post whole thing too long) where button is:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPageSiteWide.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="initial.aspx.cs" ValidateRequest="false" Inherits="initial"  UICulture="auto"%>
<%@ MasterType  virtualPath="~/MasterPageSiteWide.master"%>

<%@ Register src="~/ucBanner.ascx" TagName="Banner" TagPrefix="ucBanner"  %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>


<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
    <title>Hotline - Dealer Prior Approval - Begin</title>   
    <link href="Styles/dpaStyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
     <script type="text/javascript">

         function OpenPopUp() {
             window.open("collectvin.aspx", "List", "scrollbars=no,resizable=no,width=400,height=350");

         }


         function InvokePop(vin) {
             val = document.getElementById(vin).value;
             // to handle in IE 7.0           
             if (window.showModalDialog) {
                 retVal = window.showModalDialog("collectvin.aspx?Control1=" + vin + "&ControlVal=" + val, 'Show Popup Window', "dialogHeight:90px,dialogWidth:250px,resizable:yes,center:yes,");
                 document.getElementById(vin).value = retVal;
             }

         }


         function checkChoice() {
             var hasFound = false
             for (i = 0; i < document.secpaform.SecPACode.length; i++) {
                 if (document.secpaform.SecPACode[i].checked == true) {
                     hasFound = true
                     break;
                 }
             }

             if (!hasFound) {
                 alert("Please select one...")
                 document.secpaform.SecPACode[0].focus();
                 return false
             }
             else
                 return true
         }


         function checkOldVin() {
             //alert('inside checkOldVin');
             if (frmInitial.txtOldVin.value == '') {
                 alert('Please enter the VIN for an older vehicle!!!');
                 frmInitial.txtOldVin.focus();
                 return false;

             }
             var alphanumeric = /^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/;
             if (!frmInitial.txtOldVin.value.match(alphanumeric)) {
                 alert('VIN must be numbers and letters only!');
                 frmInitial.txtOldVin.focus();
                 return false;
             }
             return true;
         }


         function checkPartChoice() {
             //alert('in checkPartsChoice');
         }

     </script> 
      <style type="text/css">
        body {
        background: url(page-bg.gif) repeat-x top left #5997C8;  
        CLIP: rect(19px 65px 50px 10px);
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-bottom:30px;
        margin-right: 40px;
        margin-left: 60px;
        width:80%;
        }

        TD.bluerow {
        height: .10pc;
        background-color: #000066;
        }

        TD.medbluerow {
        height: .0005pc;
        background-color: #6699CC;
        }   


    p.MsoNormal
    {margin-top:0in;
    margin-right:0in;
    margin-bottom:10.0pt;
    margin-left:0in;
    line-height:115%;
    font-size:11.0pt;
    font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";
    }


    </style>  

</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">


        <!-- -------------------------->
        <!-- start outer table, rounded corners --> 
        <!-- -------------------------->
        <table style="width: 95%;" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td width="8" height="11" bgcolor="#ffffff"><img src="images/ccbackground/HLEFT.jpg" alt=""/></td>
            <td bgcolor="#ffffff" background="images/ccbackground/TOPbg.jpg"><img src="images/ccbackground/TOPbg.jpg" alt=""/></td>
            <td width="8" height="11" bgcolor="#ffffff"><img src="images/ccbackground/HRIGHT.jpg" alt=""/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="8" background="images/ccbackground/LEFTbg.jpg"><img src="images/ccbackground/LEFTbg.jpg" alt=""/></td>        
            <td align="center" height="800" valign="top" bgcolor="white" >
            <div>
                <asp:Label ID="lblTopHeading" runat="server" Font-Bold="true"  Font-Size="X-Large" Text="<%$Resources:share,lblTopHeading %>" EnableViewState="false"></asp:Label>
            </div>
            <!-- -------------------------->
            <!-- begin main page content --> 
            <!-- -------------------------->
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="tryUP" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <table width="100%" align="center" style="font-size:14px; font-family:Verdana,Arial;">
                        <tr align="center">
                            <td align="center" >
                                <br />
                                <ucBanner:Banner ID="bannerStrip" runat="server"></ucBanner:Banner>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" Text="English" Visible="false" runat="server" onclick="LinkButton1_Click"></asp:LinkButton><br />
                                <asp:Label ID="Label22" runat="server" Font-Size="Small" Text="<%$Resources:share,lblpartstatement %>" EnableViewState="false"></asp:Label>
                                <br />           
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" Text="<%$Resources:share,lblPartsList %>" Visible="true" runat="server" ></asp:LinkButton>  
                                <br />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="font-size:10px; padding-left:130px;">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblInitialHeading" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Text="" EnableViewState="false"></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                            <td align="center" valign="top">
                                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="Large" Text=""></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr align="center">
                            <td align="center">
                                <div id="Div1" class="example1" runat="server" visible="true" >
                                    <a href="javascript:window.close();" style="color:Red; float:right">
                                        <span>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblClose" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="Medium" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:share,lblClose %>"></asp:Label>
                                        </span>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                         </tr>

                        <tr align="center">
                            <td align="center" valign="top" style="font-size:16px; font-family:Verdana,Tahoma; font-weight:bold">
                                <div id="divButtons" runat="server" visible="true" >
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblPAtypeheading" runat="server"  Font-Names="Verdana" Text="<%$ Resources:share,lblPAtypeheading %>"></asp:Label>&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="lblPAtype" Font-Names="Verdana"  runat="server" Font-Underline="true" Text=""></asp:Label>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>                    
                    </table>


                   <br />
                   <div id="divPAnotrequired" runat="server" visible="false">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblNotRequired" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Text="<%$Resources:share,lblPANotRequired %>" EnableViewState="false"></asp:Label>
                        <br />
                   </div>

                <div id="divRADnotrequired" runat="server" visible="false">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Text="<%$Resources:share,lblRADNotRequired %>" EnableViewState="false"></asp:Label>
                    <br />
                </div>

                <div id="divCHMSLnotrequired" runat="server" visible="false">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Text="<%$Resources:share,lblCHMSLNotRequired %>" EnableViewState="false"></asp:Label>
                    <br />
                </div>

                <div id="divTaurusRearLampNotRequired" runat="server" visible="false">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Text="<%$Resources:share,lblTaurusRearLampNotRequired %>" EnableViewState="false"></asp:Label>
                    <br />
                </div>

                <div id="divRangerChatterNotRequired" runat="server" visible="false">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label15" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Text="<%$Resources:share,lblRangerChatterNotRequired %>" EnableViewState="false"></asp:Label>
                    <br />
                </div>

           <div id="divFlexSqueakNotRequired" runat="server" visible="false">
                <asp:Label ID="Label16" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Text="<%$Resources:share,lblFlexSqueakNotRequired %>" EnableViewState="false"></asp:Label>
                <br />
           </div>
           <div id="divEscapeNoiseNotRequired" runat="server" visible="false">
                <asp:Label ID="Label17" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Text="<%$Resources:share,lblEscapeNoiseNotRequired %>" EnableViewState="false"></asp:Label>
                <br />
            </div>
           <div id="divFiestaGlassNotRequired" runat="server" visible="false">
                <asp:Label ID="Label18" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Text="<%$Resources:share,lblFiestaGlassNotRequired %>" EnableViewState="false"></asp:Label>
                <br />
           </div>
            <div id="divScratchesNotRequired" runat="server" visible="false">
                <asp:Label ID="Label20" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Text="<%$Resources:share,lblScratchesNotRequired %>" EnableViewState="false"></asp:Label>
                <br />
           </div>
           <div id="divCostCap" runat="server" visible="false">
                <asp:Label ID="lblCostCap" runat="server" Font-Size="Medium" Font-Names="Verdana"  ForeColor="IndianRed" Font-Bold="true" Text="<%$Resources:share,lblCostCap %>" EnableViewState="false"></asp:Label>

                 <div id="closeButtonDiv" class="closeButton" runat="server" visible="true" >
                 </div>
           </div>

            <div id="divRadMileage" runat="server" visible="false">

                <div class="medBlueRow" style="width:700px; height:2px;"></div>

                <table width="90%" align="center" style="font-size:14px; font-family:Verdana,Arial;">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="font-size:16px; font-family:Verdana,Tahoma; font-weight:bold">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana"  Text="<%$Resources:share,lblRadMileage %>" EnableViewState="false"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" style="font-size:12px; font-family:Verdana,Tahoma; font-weight:bold" height="125" valign="middle">                        
                            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="btnIndexchange_Click" AutoPostBack="True">
                                <asp:ListItem Text="<%$Resources:share,lblYes %>" Value="yes"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="<%$Resources:share,lblNo %>" Value="no"></asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:RadioButtonList>             
                            <br />                       
                            &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Visible="false" Text="<%$Resources:share,btnDslParts %>" />
                            <br /><br />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

            </div>

            <div id="divCHMSL" runat="server" visible="false">

                <table width="90%" align="center" style="font-size:14px; font-family:Verdana,Arial;">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="font-size:16px; font-family:Verdana,Tahoma; font-weight:bold">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana"  Text="<%$Resources:share,lblCHMSL %>" EnableViewState="false"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" style="font-size:12px; font-family:Verdana,Tahoma; font-weight:bold" valign="middle">

                            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList2" runat="server"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="btnIndexchangeCHMSL_Click" AutoPostBack="True">
                                <asp:ListItem Text="<%$Resources:share,lblCHMSLYes %>" Value="yes"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="<%$Resources:share,lblCHMSLNo %>" Value="no"></asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Comment: Look for the line in html output with the name of your button and add it to the question

Comment: Do you mean on view source?  I have the button code above already?  I am not clear on what you mean when you say "html output" or is that the view source?

Comment: Are there your button and your event in the content page?

Comment: Please provide markup for content page.

Comment: Does everything else on that particular page work as expected?

Comment: I posted contenet (part of the page as it all wouldnt fit).

The button and the event and everything are in the contenet page not master page.

Comment: "Does everything else work" it appears to work but I cant get the button to work and that is step 1 of 3 on that page so I cant get past step 1.

The other pages I converted to use this same master page work fine though, the master page right now has no functionality to it really just rounded corners and header (going to add functionality later).

Comment: I can't seem to find any elements with `ID="btnPACheck"` in the content page you provided. What happens when you double click on the button in designer view? Does it take you to your `btnPACheck_Click` or does it create a new one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found Solution: Found the issue.

The form was doing Request. Form and that was returning NULL for all the values.

I just changed it to do the `formfield.value` instead of `request.form("FormField")`

This solved the issue.

Sorry for initial confusion on what the initial issue was.